# What is the format of an HTTP request message generated by AJAX?

Tags: ajax, http, asynchronous, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

To clarify: I am interested in what the actual HTTP request message looks like (headers etc.), *not the code* used to create it.  In other words, something like this:

```
GET /info.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
SpecialHTTPHeaderIndicatingAsynchRequest: 1
SpecialHTTPHeaderDefiningCallbackFunction: MyFunc
...
```

I am trying to work out exactly what happens when an HTTP server receives an asynchronous request: how does the server know it's asychronous, how is the call-back function passed and what response code does it give *immediately* (if any) to acknowledge the request (before serving a response to it).  I have always presumed that an HTTP server must give some sort of immediate (i.e. synchronous) response to acknowledge the request; now I'm not so sure, however.  (If it doesn't do this, how does the requesting system know that the request has been received and is being worked on, or doesn't it know this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has no idea if the request was sent from client with Synchronous or Asynchronous mode.
Now let see inside  the HTTP Request. I have made a small example with PHP and HTML/JS

**client.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
          url: "/StackOverFlow/sof/server.php",
         }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
          });   
    </script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
    print json_encode(array("NAME" => "Factory", "VALUE" => "Constructor"));
?>
```

when i start my client.html in my browser and active firebug ( free Add-In Firefox) i can see the http request sent from the client, and http response that i got from the server
[image]

Now if we look into %Apache_Home%/logs/access.log wi will see that Apache handle the Ajax request in the same way if it was from browser request(POST/GET)

```
::1 - - [18/Nov/2014:22:35:22 +0100] "GET /StackOverFlow/sof/server.php HTTP/1.1" 200 40 "http://localhost/stackoverflow/sof/client.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Halayem - that does help a bit.  So you're saying that the server will respond in the same way whether the request is synchronous or asynchronous, because it is unaware of how the request was sent - is that right?  If so, how is the callback function passed to the server?

Comment: The callback is not passed to the server. the client will wait until a data will be transmitted from the server 'like an echo or print from php' or an error happened(like 404 not found...), or client decide to close connection with server after a period of time (set timeout) without getting any information.